# How to get rid of underline on <span> inside <a> tag with hover?

Tags: html, css, anchor, text-decorations

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/ytk1smgg/1/)

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Messages<span>1</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover span {
    text-decoration: none;
}

span {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 999px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: -.5em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 .3em;
}
```

When you mouse-over the link the underline is applied to the `<span>` even though I've set `text-decoration: none`. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try changing the `display` of `<span>` to `inline-block` as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ytk1smgg/3/)**

```css
span {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 999px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: -.5em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 .3em;
    display: inline-block; /* <-- Added declaration */
}
```

### Explanation

According to [CSS level 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props), `text-decoration` is not propagated to the contents of *nested* atomic inline-level elements - such as inline-blocks and inline-tables.

> **[16.3.1 Underlining, overlining, striking, and blinking: the 'text-decoration' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props)**
>
> [...] Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and
>   absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic
>   inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Also the spec states (my emphasis):

> Underlines, overlines, and line-throughs are applied **only to text**
>   (including white space, letter spacing, and word spacing): margins,
>   borders, and padding **are skipped**. User agents **must not** render these
>   text decorations on content that is not text. For example, **images and
>   inline blocks must not be underlined**.

Also note that text decorations would stick with the text itself, therefore:

> Relatively positioning a descendant moves all text decorations affecting it along with the descendant's text; it does not affect calculation of the decoration's initial position on that line.

Comment: @DavidThomas This is because `text-decoration` is not applied to contents of **nested** `inline-block`s. The CSS2 spec [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props): `Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.`

Comment: Thanks, though I'm still surprised; I had assumed that the underline wasn't 'applied to' the descendant, but merely extended *beneath* the descendant.

Comment: @DavidThomas It is not extended even by default because according to the spec: `Underlines, overlines, and line-throughs are applied only to text [...] margins, borders, and padding are skipped` and also `Relatively positioning a descendant moves all text decorations affecting it along with the descendant's text`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation, I wasn't aware of that either +1! (why not edit that explanation in the answer itself as it doesn't seem to be obvious?)

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks. Just revised the answer.

Answer (score 3):

add this

```
ul li a span { text-decoration:none; display: inline-block; }
```