# How to un-underline a pseudo element of an element that is underlined

Tags: html, css

I've encountered this issue several times during my work and I've never understood why it happens or how to fix it.

### Setup:

```
<p id="skeeter">Even John Skeet cannot parse HTML with Regex</p>
```

---

```
#skeeter { text-decoration: underline; color: blue;}
#skeeter:after { content: "\00bb"; margin-left: 5px; text-decoration: none;}
```

---

The above has the raquo underlined, when I intend it not to be.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scar1z9k/

Answer (score 4):

With [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zg7k48zc/). Only add `display: inline-block` to `:after` tag

```
#skeeter { text-decoration: underline; color: blue;}
#skeeter:after { content: "\00bb"; margin-left: 5px; text-decoration: none; display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Because some elements in CSS don't have container behavior and some styles don't apply before take container behavior. Sorry about my explication but my english is not good. Sorry

Comment: @FailedWebDev An explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137967/how-to-get-rid-of-underline-on-span-inside-a-tag-with-hover/27138073#27138073